# CV (Coefficient of Varience) Calculaiton in R programming

Tags: r

I am trying to calculate mean, IQR, and CV. The data set is "flights_DTW" and subset is "DEP_DELAY_NEW" "NA" are not removed.
Hi is if possible to calculate CV using the following codes:

````
mean(flights_DTW$DEP_DELAY_NEW, na.rm = TRUE)
mean(flights_DTW$ARR_DELAY_NEW, na.rm = TRUE)
IQR(flights_DTW$DEP_DELAY_NEW, na.rm = TRUE)
IQR(flights_DTW$ARR_DELAY_NEW, na.rm = TRUE)
CV(flights_DTW$DEP_DELAY_NEW, na.rm = TRUE)
CV(flights_DTW$ARR_DELAY_NEW, na.rm = TRUE)

cat(sprintf("16.76 = %.2f", flights_DTW$DEP_DELAY_NEW)))```

I came up with the following result:

[1] 16.75676
[1] 16.43083
[1] 8
[1] 9
Error in CV(flights_DTW$DEP_DELAY_NEW, na.rm = TRUE) : 
  could not find function "CV"
What I want is that I want to put everything in a command.
````

Comment: A quick google search using "CV function R package" does not turn up any R package with a CV() function. There do seem to be packages with a cv() function. Remember that R is case sensitive so CV is not the same as cv. Of course it is not difficult to compute CV from base R functions.

Comment: Greetings! Usually it is helpful to provide a minimally reproducible dataset for questions here so people can troubleshoot your problems. One way of doing this is by using the `dput` function. You can find out how to use it here: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to install a package just for one function, you can define your own cv function as:

```
CV <- function(x, na.rm=TRUE){
  sd(x, na.rm = na.rm)/mean(x, na.rm = na.rm)
}

> CV(mtcars$mpg)
[1] 0.2999881
```